# Android android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, regex, email

Today we experienced strange pattern behaviour.

For instance, on tablet with 3.2 stock rom(previously 4.0.+) it works well.

But on some other 3.2 tablets and 4.0 devices it doesn't.

Function to test email functionality is like:

```
public static boolean checkEmail(CharSequence emailAddress){
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ){
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress).matches();
    }
    ....
```

So this is what I have in 16'th sources for email addres pattern(JAVA code):

```
public static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS
    = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
        "\\@" +
        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
        "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
        ")+"
    );
```

Here is 'normalised' version:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}\\@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25})+
```

[Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)(**JS** regex validator) tells that this regexp is mostly proper, but in round brace the `\\.` should be `\.` and `\\@` should be `\@` to work in regexpal.

Moreover it is not quite clear, why there are two '\+' group of symbols in first braces?

Comment: My guess the regex flavor used is not the same across the different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our current solution, which worked:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}[\\@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}([\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25})+
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of pattern using `Pattern.pattern()` function from a device on which is works and make your own `Pattern` object out of it. This way you won't have differences in implementations across devices. Same goes for `Geocoder`, which didn't work for me on some devices.

Comment: best answer!! (api 8)