# android email verification error's with apostrophes

Tags: java, android, regex, email

Given apostrophes exist and some email providers like them; lets assume they are valid email chars. No arguments please.

Now given this assumption - the following android code fails the apostrophe test;

```
return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("michaelo'reilly@yahoo.com").matches();
```

it returns 'false' when it should return 'true'

How can i resolve this? regex?

Comment: nope - i have many people from around the world who would disagree. no arguments means...

Comment: I didn't say it's _correct_. I said that _according to Android_ it isn't, and their regex brooks no argument. Don't use their regex if it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: i did already but you knew what was meant already. any ideas QPaysTaxes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545974/android-android-util-patterns-email-address-strange-behaviour list some regexes. You could just take that and add the quote character to the accepted chars.

Comment: fantatsic, thx JP Moresmau - stickan answer down with a bit of code and i'll amrk as 'answered'

Comment: @JP Moresmau - im having issues inserting this in to my code (prob due to my lack of regex knowledge), can you put an answer up?

Comment: The example email you have given isnt actually valid for that particular provider: "Only letters, numbers, underscores, and one period are allowed." But RFC2821 and RFC2822 allow them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the expression given at [Android android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545974/android-android-util-patterns-email-address-strange-behaviour) and adding a single quote in the list of accepted characters before the @:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+']{1,256}[\\@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}([\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25})+
```

This matches michaelo'reilly@yahoo.com.